# Where does outlook store tasks & calendar information?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Where are does outlook store tasks & calendar information? Is it in the .Pst file itself? If so, is there any way to view it?

Answer (score 3):

If it's an exchange mailbox, then on the exchange server.  If it's connected to Windows Live (with the Outlook Connector pack), then on Windows Live's servers.  Otherwise, yes: in the .pst.

Comment: And if it's Outlook 2010, it could be connected to a remote iCal file.

Comment: Does 2010 not still store info locally in a .pst file (Internet Calendar Subscriptions.pst)?

Comment: AFAIK, even with Exchange some data is cached locally in PST.